# access database changes didn't reflect on IIS

Tags: asp.net

I've an ASP.NET application uses access database. I added a new table into database. I filled a dropdownlist with data that selected from the new table. The application works on my local machine. But after I deployed the application on IIS there is no data in the dropdownlist. In a weird way the changes made to database didn't reflect to IIS. Is there any setting on IIS I should set to make IIS perceive the new table?

Comment: Have you copied your database along with other project files to your remote server?

Comment: Yes, I can see the database in my project folder on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Make certain there are modify permissions for IUSR, IIS_IUSR, LOCAL & NETWORK SERVICE to the folder where the access db file is, usually that's the problem on updates or creates with them.